# libjsoncpp linking error in Ubuntu 16

Tags: c++, json, linux, ubuntu

I have been trying to link with libjsoncpp on Ubuntu 16.04 but keep on getting the same error, even after reinstalling all json libraries in the system.

```
undefined reference to `Json::Value::getMemberNames() const'
undefined reference to `Json::Value::operator[](std::string const&)'
undefined reference to `Json::Value::asString() const'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This code use to compile out-of-the-box with libjsoncpp in Ubuntu 14.04

locate libjsoncpp gives me this:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjsoncpp.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjsoncpp.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjsoncpp.so.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjsoncpp.so.1.7.2
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What's the ld command line?

Comment: Found a fix. Some installation changed the compile from gcc-5.4 to gcc-4.8. After changing the compiler back to gcc-5.4, it worked. I am not sure why this fixed the problem though.